# Pandas: How to find the average length of days for a local outbreak to peak in a COVID-19 dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframe containing the difference in number of active cases from previous value in each country:

```
[in]
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
active_cases = {'Day(s) since outbreak':['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 'Australia':[np.NaN, 10, 10, -10, -20, -20], 'Albania':[np.NaN, 20, 0, 15, 0, -20], 'Algeria':[np.NaN, 25, 10, -10, 20, -20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(active_cases)
df

[out]
    Day(s) since outbreak   Australia   Albania     Algeria
0             0                   NaN       NaN         NaN
1             1                  10.0      20.0        25.0
2             2                  10.0       0.0        10.0
3             3                 -10.0      15.0       -10.0
4             4                 -20.0       0.0        20.0
5             5                 -20.0     -20.0       -20.0
```

I need to find the average length of days for a local outbreak to peak in this COVID-19 dataframe.

My solution is to find the nth row with the first negative value in each column (e.g., nth row of first negative value in 'Australia': 3, nth row of first negative value in 'Albania': 5) and average it.

However, I have no idea how to do this in Panda/Python.

Are there any ways to perform this task with simple lines of Python/Panda code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `set_index` the column `Day(s) since outbreak`, then use `iloc` to select all rows except the first one, then check where the values are less than (`lt`) 0. Use `idxmax` to get the first row where the value is less than 0 and take the `mean`. With your input, it gives:

```
print (df.set_index('Day(s) since outbreak')\
         .iloc[1:, :].lt(0).idxmax().astype(float).mean()) 
3.6666666666666665
```

Answer (score 0):

IICU
using df.where mask negatives and replace positives with np.NaN and then calculate the mean

```
cols= ['Australia','Albania','Algeria']
df.set_index('Day(s) since outbreak', inplace=True)
m = df< 0
df2=df.where(m, np.NaN)
#df2 = df2.replace(0, np.NaN)
df2.mean()
```

Result

[image]